# How to connect DataSnap client to DataSnap server via proxy server?

Tags: http, delphi, proxy, client, datasnap

The problem is this:

I decided to make a messenger/chat (VCL application) with callback on DataSnap technology (IDE Delphi XE6), has created a simple DataSnap server (tcp / ip + http) without the database, and thick client.

All works fine if the whole thing run on a local network (tcp / ip) or via the Internet (http).Problems arise when run over HTTP and the client machine has a HTTP proxy server, the client application can not connect to my DataSnap server application. Client application gets error **"`10061 connection refused`"** 
or **"`Expected datasnap context in request http://[YourServerIP]:[YourPort]/datasnap/tunnel`"**.

I tried to enter IP and port of the proxy server to params of component **`TSQLConnection.Driver`** params **`DSProxyHost`** and **`DSProxyPort`**, turned off my firewall and antivirus software, checked allows traffic to the proxy ip + port, but the problem has not disappeared.

After few days searches, without results, i decided listening requests from client application and response of my DataSnap Server application in **`HTTPTrace`** procedure of **`DSHTTPService1`** component, also with software *HTTPDebugerPro*, and i noticed interesting thing:

- when client app connecting to ds server app without proxy server, in request ds server app receive **`URI`** with this text **"`/datasnap/tunnel`"** and all works fine ds server response **"`200, OK`"**.
- when client app connecting to ds server app with proxy, in request ds server app receive **`URI`** with text **"`http://[YourServerIP]:[YourPort]/datasnap/tunnel`"** and raised exception with response error **"`404, Expected datasnap context in request http://YourServerIP:YourPort/datasnap/tunnel`"**.

Has anyone knows solution about this problem? How to connect DataSnap client to DataSnap server via proxy server? I searched solution for this problem several days, I shoveled the Internet but have not yet found a solution.

Comment: Have you checked whether your firewall blocks or allows traffic to the proxy ip + port?

Comment: @MartynA you wellcome [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129020/rad-studio-for-android)